How to Mock Kafka Client for Unittesting in NestJS
I am new to Typescript and currently do not understand how to mock a Kafka Client in a NestJS Application.
What I want to achieve
I have a NestJS Application which has the following controller:
consumer.controller.ts
import { Controller} from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventPattern, Payload } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { ConsumerService } from './consumer.service';

@Controller()
export class ConsumerController {
  constructor(private readonly consumerService: ConsumerService) {}

  /**
   * Handles events from the 'Topic-1' topic.
   * @param context - The Kafka context containing the message and metadata.
   */
  @EventPattern('Topic-1')
  async dosomething(@Payload() message: any) {
    // do something
  }
}

consumer.service.ts
import { Injectable, OnModuleDestroy, OnModuleInit, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Client, ClientKafka } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Injectable()
export class ConsumerService implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  constructor() {}

  @Client(microserviceConfig)
  private readonly client: ClientKafka;

  /**
   * Lifecycle hook that is called when the module is destroyed.
   * Closes the Kafka client connection.
   */
  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.client.close();
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    const requestPatterns = [
      'Topic-1',
      'Topic-2',
    ];

    requestPatterns.forEach((pattern) => {
      this.client.subscribeToResponseOf(pattern);
    });

    await this.client.connect();
  }
}


I skipped the microserviceconfig for the real KafkaClient because I want to Use my Kafka Mock for Unit testing.
This is the module
consumer.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConsumerController } from './consumer.controller';
import { ConsumerService } from './consumer.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [ConsumerController],
  providers: [ConsumerService],
})
export class ConsumerModule {}


And this is My Unit-Test for the Service:
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ConsumerService } from "./consumer.service";
import { ClientKafka } from '@nestjs/microservices';

describe('ConsumerService', () => {
  let emailService: ConsumerService;
  let kafka: ClientKafka;
  let emailNotificationService: EmailNotificationService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ConsumerService,
        {
          provide: ClientKafka,
          useValue: {
            subscribeToResponseOf: jest.fn(),
            connect: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined),
            emit: jest.fn(),
          }
        }
      ],
    }).compile();

    emailService = module.get(ConsumerService);
    kafka = module.get(ClientKafka);
  });


    it('Subscribe to right topics', async() => {
      await emailService.onModuleInit();
      expect(kafka.subscribeToResponseOf).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Topic-1');
      expect(kafka.subscribeToResponseOf).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Topic-2');
    })
});

But when I run the tests I get an error when trying to call this.client which indicates client is null.
I guess that is because Dependency Injection of my Kafka Mock is not working. Do I need to add the ClientKafka to the constructor? I tried doing that, but then building the consumer.module.ts failed.
How to do this?

KafkaJS and NestJS should already have tests for Kafka integration... Have you tried looking at those? Or, have you considered using TestContainers?
